# UITableViewRowAction code is not executed

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to build a swipeable tablecell. Code of the following URL is working
https://github.com/vanyas/ActionRowTest

But when I implement similar code in my project, It doesn't work. In my code, the following snippet is not working, that's why I can't see the options after swiping.

```
UITableViewRowAction *actionRed =
[UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal
 title:@"Delete"
 handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)         
 [weakSelf.tasklist removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [weakSelf.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
 [weakSelf.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]                                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];         
 }];
```

The whole snippet of my code can be found here.
https://gist.github.com/reza-ryte-club/a3d59b0a3f6c391b831e

Comment: You only returned `actionRed` https://gist.github.com/reza-ryte-club/a3d59b0a3f6c391b831e#file-gistfile1-txt-L164

Comment: That is not a problem. I cloned the source I mentioned, I changed that code according to me, that code worked.

Comment: The source is also worked for me. I checked your snippet, couldn't find anything wrong.